# How changes packet relating to Idr packet in h264 over rtp?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I read  [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) , if I uderstand well in video flow there are sps and pps packets(meta data) then Idr (full image) and then changes packet between last idr to current state, and again from the beginning.

I know that for each rtp packet header that wrap h264 data has sequence number .

What I don't understand , Is to changes packets (that came between Idr packets) how do they know to each Idr they relate ?

Is there in h264  header/data that write to which rtp sequence number or h264 sequence number they relate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Every slice has a slice header. It’s documented in iso 14496-10.

Comment: which header do you mean? in h264 header there are  1 /2 bytes(in fragment packet) , in this header there is no relate for which Idr it relate, in rtp header there is 12 bytes that write there sequence number, but this header not relate for another packets , I not find in h264 header frame number / frame related

Comment: The slice_header() It comes after the 1/2 byte nal_unit() for nalu_unit_types 1 and 5. Please take a look at ISO 14496-10 Its all in there.